# What is the Relationship between HDFS Block Size and Network Replication Traffic?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, replication, opentsdb

Our HBase cluster has a significant amount of network traffic relative to the amount of data we believe we are writing to it via OpenTSDB.

Relayed Bytes to OpenTSDB:

[image]

Network Throughput in *Bytes* (Y Axis is SI units, so not base2):

[image]

We use Cloudera, so the block is 128MB, would changing it to 64MB reduce network replication traffic? Are there other consequences to consider?

Comment: What are relay.bytes and bond.bytes? Are these linux counters or is it coming from network gear? Other than 3x DFS replication, could it be related to backend tasks in the database itself? If you were to build a chart for several days, are there any schedule-based or user-activity based patterns that are visible?

Comment: @SergeiRodionov The only backend tasks that I am aware of is OpenTSDB compactions (Those are different than HBase compactions). bond.bytes is coming from the Linux gear - it will be the same as what the switch ports show. relay.bytes is the how much the application sends to OpenTSDB (and is JSON compressed). So I expect it to be much smaller. But even without the activity spikes, the shows 10x network traffic multiplication (even without 3xDFS). What I am mainly interested in is how the block size relates to replication size.

Comment: Not sure how to read those charts, but 1k/sec seems low for any meaningful ingestion traffic. Does this counter stand the test of manually checking ifconfig for RX bytes. We're on the default 64Mb setting and haven't seen a good reason to change it. So no particular advice on block size.

Comment: I found descriptions here: https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/blob/master/cmd/bosun/web/web.go - bosun.relay.bytes = Bytes per second relayed from Bosun to the backend server. os.net.bond.bytes = The rate at which bytes are sent or received over bonded network adapters. One thing I can think of is that the size of HBase Put on the wire can be  different from its heapsize and incoming json data.

Comment: For what its worth, i installed bosun in a container and relay bytes chart shows 700 bytes/sec on average. Not far from 1.2k/sec on the top chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer plainly the question of *will lowering block size reduce replication traffic*, the answer is **no**.

HDFS clients do not write entire block worth of data at once - they stream the writes in small checksummed packets of 64k-128k bytes at a time (configurable), building towards the entire block at the DataNode(s) in the pipeline.

Lowering the block size will only have one effect: more blocks across more DataNodes. It *will not* alter the rates of transfer and the total network utilisation, which is entirely driven by the goal data write size and the replication factor and not by the HDFS logical block size attribute.